# Factory function does not decrement DOM values

Tags: javascript, object, factory, decrement

I have this factory function, where I set my values and then the values should decrement every time a button is clicked, i.e I have two buttons and two values for each button

Here is my code, please let me know where I got it wrong

```
let itemsLeftOne = { value: 101 };
let itemsLeftTwo = { value: 64 };

firstItemsElement.forEach(element => element.textContent = itemsLeftOne.value);
secondItemsElement.forEach(element => element.textContent = itemsLeftTwo.value);

function subtractItemsLeft(input) {
    if (input === '1') {
        console.log('One');
        return itemsLeftOne.value--;
    } else if (input === '2') {
        console.log('Two');
        return itemsLeftTwo.value--;
    }
}
```

This is where I called the function

```
function calculateDonations(event) {
    const el = event.target;

    if(el.nodeName !== 'BUTTON' || !el.classList.contains('submitBtn')) return;

    let targetInput = el.dataset.input;
    subractItemsLeft(targetInput);
    successModal();
}
```

I get the correct button on the console but it doesn't do the subtraction.

Comment: where and how have you called `subtractItemsLeft` function? pls share more part of your code

Comment: Please check the edited question